# Jekyll javascript's compression on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, compression, jekyll, minify, github-pages

Is there any way/solution/plugin to compress JS used with Jekyll and hosted on Github Pages? Github doesn't accept any minify/compress plugins ([list here](https://pages.github.com/versions/)). I can't do it by gulp bc engine will overwrites it. So, is there any possibility to reach this out?

Answer (score 0):

[Bypass Jekyll on GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages), compute output folder locally and commit.